# Google Hangouts like "ago" timespan

Tags: android, html, date, time

I've been trying to use

[`DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html#getRelativeTimeSpanString(android.content.Context,%20long,%20boolean))

…to generate elapsed time strings similar to the Google Hangouts app.

However, I'm getting strings like:

```
1 min ago
58 min ago
10 hours ago
yesterday
3 days ago
1 week ago
```

The Hangouts app shows strings like:

```
Now
58 min ago
11:05     (if time is more than 1 hour ago, it'll show the original time)
yesterday
Wed       (if the day was more than 1 day ago, it'll show the day)
July 21   (if more than 1 wee ago, it'll show the date)
```

The Hangouts-like format is what I'm looking for.

Just curious if I'm using the wrong flags with this method, or if the Hangouts app uses a different method/library to generate the time span strings. I could do a custom implementation if DateUtils doesn't provide what I'm looking for.

Comment: Your question is not clear. If you want to show a date-time, just use a formatter to create s string representation of the date-time while avoiding the relative time class entirely. Perhaps you can edit your question to clarify and post more examples of what you want .

Comment: I added a more clear example of how DateUtils.geRelativeTimeSpanString(); returns time-span strings vs how the hangots app displays time-span strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing a combination of different DateUtils formatters:

```
@SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
public static String getTimeSpanString(Context mContext, long time, boolean showTime) {

    int flags = DateUtils.FORMAT_ABBREV_RELATIVE | DateUtils.FORMAT_ABBREV_ALL;

    if(showTime) {
        flags |= DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_TIME;
    }

    long now = new Date().getTime();
    long duration = now - time;

    if(duration < DateUtils.HOUR_IN_MILLIS) {
        return DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(time, now, 0, flags).toString();
    } else if (DateUtils.isToday(time)) {
        SimpleDateFormat timeInstance;
        if(DateFormat.is24HourFormat(mContext)) {
            timeInstance = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
        } else {
            timeInstance = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
        }

        return timeInstance.format(time);
    } else if (duration < DateUtils.WEEK_IN_MILLIS) {
        return DateUtils.formatDateTime(mContext,time,flags | DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_WEEKDAY);
    }

    return DateUtils.formatDateTime(mContext, time, flags | DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_DATE);
}
```